# Sortable UUIDs and overriding ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, uuid

I'm wanting to use UUIDs in an app I'm building and am running into a bit of a problem. Due to UUIDs (v4) not being sortable because they're randomly generated, I'm trying to override ActiveRecord::Base#first, but Rails isn't too pleased with that. It yells at me saying `ArgumentError: You tried to define a scope named "first" on the model "Item", but Active Record already defined a class method with the same name.` Do I *have* to use a different method if I want to sort and have it sort correctly?

Here's the sauce:

```
# lib/sortable_uuid.rb
module SortableUUID
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      scope :first, -> { order("created_at").first }
      scope :last, -> { order("created_at DESC").first }
    end
  end
end


# app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SortableUUID
end
```

Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2.2

Reference:

- http://blog.nakonieczny.it/posts/rails-support-for-uuid/
- http://linhmtran168.github.io/blog/2014/03/17/postgres-uuid-in-rails/ ( Drawbacks section )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [`first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) and [`last`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last) aren't as simple as you seem to think they are: you're completely neglecting the `limit` argument that both of those methods support.

Secondly, `scope` is little more than a fancy way of adding class methods that are intended to return queries. Your scopes are abusing `scope` because they return single model instances rather than queries. You don't want to use `scope` at all, you're just trying to replace the `first` and `last` class methods so why don't you just override them? You'd need to override them properly though and that will require reading and understanding the Rails source so that you properly mimic what [`find_nth_with_limit`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/430a09514a4ad1d0f8481f18a42c4813b6b61e38/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L504) does. You'd want to override `second`, `third`, ... and the rest of those silly methods while you're at it.

If you don't feel right about replace `first` and `last` (a good thing IMO), then you could add a default scope to order things as desired:

```
default_scope -> { order(:created_at) }
```

Of course, default scopes come with their own set of problems and sneaking things into the ORDER BY like this will probably force you into calling [`reorder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder) any time you actually want to specify the ORDER BY; remember that multiple calls to `order` add new ordering conditions, they don't replace one that's already there.

Alternatively, if you're using Rails6+, you can use [Markus's `implicit_order_column` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56345057/479863) to avoid all the problems that default scopes can cause.

---

I think you're going about this all wrong. Any time I see `M.first` I assume that something has been forgotten. Ordering things by `id` is pretty much useless so you should **always** manually specify the order you want before using methods like `first` and `last`.

Comment: Please note, [this](https://tekin.co.uk/2018/12/configurable-implicit-ordering-in-activerecord-models-coming-in-rails-6) article says "Default scopes can lead to all sorts of strange bugs and confusing behaviour". This may be a better solution: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34480#issue-231798255

Comment: @stevec I don't disagree, I'm not a fan of default scopes and I've sworn at them more than once. Markus's `implicit_order_column` approach is a good solution if you're in Rails6+.

Answer (score 6):

Rails 6 (currently in version 6.0.0rc1) comes to rescue with [implicit_order_column](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema.html#method-c-implicit_order_column-3D)!

To order by `created_at` and make `.first`, `.last`, `.second` etc. respect it is as simple as:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.implicit_order_column = :created_at
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After replacing `id` with `uuid`, I experienced some weirdness in the way associations were allocating foreign keys, and it wasn't that `.last` and `.first`, but instead because I simply forgot to add `default: 'gen_random_uuid()'` to one of the tables using a uuid. Once I fixed that, the problem was solved.

```
create_table :appointments, id: :uuid, default: 'gen_random_uuid()' do |t|
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this according to the rails documentation linked [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_postgresql.html#uuid-primary-keys) is to ensure you add the default option for your UUID you would like to use. A good write up on choosing a UUID linked [here](https://blog.daveallie.com/ulid-primary-keys). I used ULIDs as they are sortable and with specifying my UUID option as the ULID, my records are sortable!