# .order on ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone column doesn't order correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I am calling

```
Appointment.order(:start_time)
```

And I get back an `ActiveRecord_Relation` that isn't ordered according to start_time as expected.

Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was using a default scope, which are [prone to introducing bugs](https://piechowski.io/post/why-is-default-scope-bad-rails/) like the one I had.

Once I removed the default scope and restarted the application, the problem went away.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56345057/5783745